# Object initialization in swift

Tags: swift, initialization

What would be a good practice for object initialization in swift from given below? And why?

**1. Initialize while declaring**

```
class MyClass {
    var object: MyObject = MyObject()
}
```

**2. Initialize in init()**

```
class MyClass {

    var object: MyObject

    init() {
        object = MyObject()
    }
}
```

If there are any other approaches then feel free to give suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

In this simple case, it's better to assign a value to `object` right at declaration, there's no need to do it in the initializer of `MyClass`.

So you can simply do:

```
class MyClass {
    let object = MyObject()
}
```

However, there might be more complicated scenarios, such as when `MyObject` itself has an initializer with input parameters, which only become known at the initialization of `MyClass` when you can't initialize `object` at declaration, so you need to do it in the initializer of `MyClass`.

```
class MyObject {
    let prop: String

    init(_ prop:String){
        self.prop = prop
    }
}

class MyClass {
    let object: MyObject

    init(objectProp:String){
        self.object = MyObject(objectProp)
    }
}
```